# How do I watch a local Git repo for head changes?

Tags: c#, .net, git

I am working on a project which requires me to watch a git repo for any head changes i.e. any git commits, branch changes etc.

Is there any library or nuget to do this programmatically (in .NET)? If not, any suggestions for possible approaches to do this?

Comment: Most good git systems have the ability to call a webhook when things change, that's the safest way to do this.

Comment: Where is this repo stored?  On some hosting solution (and if so, which one), on the local disk, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor a local .git/refs folder for changes. You can use libgit2sharp if you need to understand what changed. Monitoring a remote git server will either require some kind of hook script, or polling the repository on a timer.